# Android: different objects in one list

Tags: android

I am a new to android developing. I am developing an android app for a shopping mall...
i want to have a screen where a list is displayed. Name of the mall and its photo should be displayed in the first section with its short one line address...
In the next sections the products should be displayed in the same way....
Product photo, Product Name and its price...
Please suggest me what topics should i read to create such a screen....
could fragments be used to create this screen???
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Should shops and products be in the same list?

Comment: Yeah there's so many solutions you can come up with this information, you should add more specifics

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6upsx1y3ecb6ec/Shopping%20mall.bmp
this is how the screen should look like.......also the products section should be clickable...i.e. when user clicks on a particular product it should navigate to another screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. Like you can create a Customized List view for each screen. You can first create an Array List of objects of MallClassPojo. Like:

```
ArrayList<MallClassPojo> mallList.
```

Where your MallClassPojo contains the getter setter methods for Mall name,Mall image url or resourceID and short description of mall. Pass this mallList to your adapter class. Retrieve the details and show them in your customised List View. The next screen can be prepared in the same way also.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6upsx1y3ecb6ec/Shopping%20mall.bmp This is how the screen should look like....also the products section should be clickable...i.e. when user clicks on a particular product it should navigate to another screen

Answer (score -1):

Well then you can create an Array List of JSON objects. In a JSON Object you can add different data like in one object you can add the company data and in another you can add product data. Isn't it?